# Word for "not consciously aware of"

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word to convey the meaning "not consciously aware of"?

Comment: Perhaps oblivious...

Comment: You should expand this question by giving some examples of when/how you might use the word. As it is now, your question seems too vague.  For example, what's wrong with _unaware_? You could be unaware that there's a snake on the ground in front of you, you could be unaware of an old proof to a math problem, you could be unaware of a smear of ketchup on your chin. In what context are you thinking of using this word?

Comment: [Unconscious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unconscious) will fit in most cases.

Comment: You could say he is a *madman*...

Comment: Do you mean "aware, but not conscious of the awareness" (if that's even possible) or "unaware"?

Answer (score 2):

[*Subliminal* is defined as:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subliminal)

> existing or functioning below the threshold of consciousness or below the threshold of conscious perception

A subliminal message is one that you may not be consciously aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Incognizant or incognisant, depending on whether you're concerned with English or US spelling.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/incognisant

Answer (score 0):

Oblivious, incognizant, unconscious(ly)... unaware... unawares...